# Envelop Id is not sync on docusign sandbox

Tags: android, docusignapi

After loading the template, I use the template for the signature by

```
DSTemplateDelegate templateDelegate = DocuSign.getInstance().getTemplateDelegate();
// DSEnvelopeDefaults envelopeDefaults - This can be used to pre-fill the template values such as recipients, emails, tabs etc.
// Refer to javadoc for more info about DSEnvelopeDefaults.
templateDelegate.useTemplate(context, templateId, envelopeDefaults, true, new DSUseTemplateListener(){
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String envelopeId) {
        // TODO: Handle when the template has been successfully signed.
    }
     
    @Override
    public void onCancel(String templateId, String envelopeId) {
        // TODO: Handle when the signing ceremony is cancelled
    }
     
    @Override
    public void onError(DSTemplateException exception) {
        // TODO: Handle error when there is an exception while using the template or during signing
    }
});
```

After make signature it return an envelope Id, But in the sandbox, there is no envelop id is generated.
Please me to resolve this issues

Answer (score 0):

After receiving the envelopeId in `onComplete(String envelopeId)` of `useTemplate()` api, you can invoke `DocuSign.getInstance().getEnvelopeDelegate().syncAllEnvelopes()` api which will sync the envelope to DocuSign. Then, you can refer to the envelope that is synced/completed in the sandbox/DocuSign web portal.

Comment: Hii, Thanks for your reply I had done the same, and in the callback `onEnvelopeSyncSuccess(localEnvelopeId: kotlin.String, serverEnvelopeId: kotlin.String?)` it returns local and new envelop id but when I checked sandbox/DocuSign web portal there is no any envelop entry, It empty.

Comment: If you point the environment to DEMO environment using SDK api, you can check signed/completed envelope if you navigate to https://demo.docusign.net in web.
If you point the environment to PROD environment using SDK api, you can check signed/completed envelope if you navigate to https://docusign.net in web